# Java Error unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, exception, ping

I am making a code in which this program sends a ping request to the other machine.

```
import java.io.*;

class NetworkPing
{
    private static boolean pingIP(String host) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
            boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win");

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", isWindows? "-n" : "-c", "1", host);
        Process proc = processBuilder.start();

        int returnVal = proc.waitFor();
        return returnVal == 0;

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        pingIP("127.0.0.1");
    }
}
```

In this code, I am getting this error

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                pingIP("127.0.0.1");
```

It is showing error on this line

```
pingIP("127.0.0.1");
```

What is wrong with the code even I am throwing the exception in the pingIP function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pingIp` function **throws exception**, so when you call it in main you have to either **handle the exception** there, or **throw the exceptions** from main. In java you cant have `unhandled exceptions`. so you could do it like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    pingIP("127.0.0.1");
}
```

or this :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
       pingIP("127.0.0.1");
    } catch(IOException ex){
       //TODO handle exception
    } catch(InterruptedException ex){
       //TODO handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try-catch` block to handle exception:

```
try{
   pingIP("127.0.0.1");
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or use `throws`

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    pingIP("127.0.0.1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
   pingIP("127.0.0.1");
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

or make it throws in public static void main(String args[])throws IOException.
```

Answer (score 1):

remove throws for pingIP method and Place the code inside try catch blocks

Try the below code

```
class NetworkPing
{
    private static boolean pingIP(String host) 
    {
         Boolean b = false;
       try{
            boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win");

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", isWindows? "-n" : "-c", "1", host);
        Process proc = processBuilder.start();

        int returnVal = proc.waitFor();
        b = (returnVal == 0)
       }
       catch(IOException e){}
       catch(InterruptedException e){}
       catch(Exception e){}

        return b;

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        pingIP("127.0.0.1");
    }
}
```